# How to show text in textbox like Facebook shows when we select any item form dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

How to show text in textbox like facebook shows when we select any item form dropdown list?
I want to know the concept if how they modified it?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I have no idea what you mean by "Show text in textbox like facebook shows" or how it relates to a dropdown list

Comment: sorry i m actually asking about taging i search and got the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can have a look at [this](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you mean, but it sounds something like you want to update a textbox when an option on a list is selected? If that is the case you might want to use ajax for that. Here is a very nice tutorial... it is quite easy to understand and there are examples too. Hope it helps!

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/